# how to align divs inside a td horizontally?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, html-table, horizontal-alignment

[image]

as shown in the image,things are deranged a bit, maybe its because its inside a td.
is it possible to do that?

```
 <td>
    <div class="col"> 
       <div class="input-group text-center">                           
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button-minus"> - </button>
                </div>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" size="1">

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button-plus"> + </button>
                </div>
                                                
                                      
         </div> <!-- input-group.// --> 
      </div> <!-- Col.// -->
  </td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by align horizontally? Do you want the buttons and form on the same line?

Comment: yeah. thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

You might try to remove the default Bootstrap padding and margin for `td`, `p`, `button` and try :

```
td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the buttons and form on the same line by adding `display: inline-flex` to .input-group

```css
.input-group {display: inline-flex}
```

```html
 <td>
    <div class="col"> 
       <div class="input-group text-center">                           
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button-minus"> - </button>
                </div>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="1" size="1">

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="button-plus"> + </button>
                </div>
                                                
                                      
         </div> <!-- input-group.// --> 
      </div> <!-- Col.// -->
  </td>
```